# Path problem with javascript/php

Tags: php, javascript

I've been developing my site with the site directory structure as

```
www
  img
  javascript
  include
  index.php
```

Now I want to change it to

```
www
   index.php
   dir1
   dir2
   ...
   themes
       theme1
          img
          javascript
          include
          index.php
```

At the theme level index.php, earlier I've my paths to javscript files as `javascript/file1.js` or so.

Now I've changed the paths to `<?php echo THEME_PATH . "javascript/file1.js"?>`

This includes the js files, however my problem is when I reached inside the js file.

For example, in one script.js file, I've a jquery method called as

`$('#pop-con').html('<p><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" width="220" height="19" /></p>');`

I can't use php inside the js file. So how do I change the paths similar to the php implementation above??

Comment: Did you solve the problem? :-)

Comment: I have added a comment to my answer.

Comment: Please don't put the answer in your question. Instead you should mark your own answer as `Best answer`.

Answer (score 2):

**Relative paths**

Probably one of the easiest ways to solve it is using relative paths.

In your case you will need to be one directory up (../), so it would be:

```
$('#pop-con').html('<p><img src="../img/ajax-loader.gif" width="220" height="19" /></p>');
```

Comment: I tried this method but the directory comes relative to the home directory, ie that `www/index.php`, not from the `www/themes/theme1/javascript/` directory, which is where the js file is resideing.. :/

Comment: @ptamzz: Did you know about base url in HTML? Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @ptamzz: You are welcome. You could set the base url once for each theme and then use relative paths to your images. ;-)

Comment: Maybe if you can put this HTML base thing on your answer above, I can mark your answer the best one as it actually solved the issue the best way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a small `<script>` on your pages that creates a global variable to store the "THEME_PATH" value:

```
<script>
  window['THEME_PATH'] = '<?php echo THEME_PATH?>';
</script>
```

Then your JavaScript files can just look for the global variable and use it to construct paths. I keep such code in a global template header that's used for all the pages in my application. There really are only a very small number of things like that to worry about; in my application I think there are like 4 or 5 items of information like that to communicate with included .js files.

Comment: the same idea, but `window['THEME_PATH']` doesn't work. I changed it to `window.themPath`. Now it's working. :)

Comment: Well there's no reason that `window['THEME_PATH']` would not work; I just tested it out and it does. That's perfectly legal JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Solution, in case anyone else need it.

I put the following code in my theme level index.php file

```
<script>
    window.themePath =  "<?php echo $site_info[theme_style_path]; ?>";
</script>
```

And use the javascript global variable to append the path.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the Javascript is irrelevant for the purposes of HTML being embedded within the page. What matters is the location of the page the HTML is embedded within.

For instance, if you load a page from `example.com/index.php`, and some Javascript loaded from `example.com/js/script.js` inserts some HTML into the main page, then image path references are going to be relative to `/`, as that's where the page was loaded from, not from `/js`.

As for embedding PHP in JS, you're right - but you can have PHP emit a .js file trivially:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/javascript');
?>

var settings = <?php echo json_encode($SETTINGS_ARRAY); ?>;
```

would generate perfectly valid Javascript, even thought it came from a PHP file.